# When setting up a esp32 for an asynchronous web server, can there be code within the void loop()?

Tags: esp32

I have ran into a couple examples that don't really have any code written in the void loop() section when using the esp32 as an asynchronous web server. Just curious if I can run other code there before I begin designing some things out.

Comment: i'm guessing this examples run upone some interupts ... if the code of  interupts dosn't block the return to the main Loop so **yas you coude write a program in the main loop**  ... you have to provide some code examples to have a good help , try to read[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Of course, let me post the link of the example I am looking at. Please draw your attention to the esp32 Server code. https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-client-server-wi-fi/?unapproved=479067&moderation-hash=cd02c06414a8217f84cc0585eab24f61#comment-479067

Comment: that code will use asynchronous web server ... you could write code in your LOOP it will run normlly and when http request come to server it will handle by the [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=vs-2019#:~:text=A%20lambda%20can%20introduce%20new,by%20value%20or%20by%20reference.) functions wich you define in `on` method ... @romkay answer has a good explanation on how it work under the hood

Comment: Perfect, I feel a lot more comfortable moving forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The Arduino Core for the ESP32 runs over the [ESP-IDF](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf) (Espressif IoT Development Framework). ESP-IDF uses a port of [FreeRTOS](https://freertos.org). FreeRTOS provides lightweight tasks.

The async web server uses [AsyncTCP](https://github.com/me-no-dev/AsyncTCP), which uses its own task for event callbacks. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/me-no-dev/AsyncTCP/blob/master/src/AsyncTCP.cpp#L216).

`loop()` is just a task. You can still run your own code in it (and make your own tasks if you want that much asynchrony). You can see the code that calls `loop()` [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/main.cpp#L12).

These tasks are non-preemptive - only one can run at a time, no others can do anything until a task voluntarily yields control of the processor (using `yield()` or `delay()` in the Arduino Core).

For callbacks from the async web server you should do the work you need to do and then return as soon as possible - don't yield or call `delay()` in its callbacks or you may block the TCP and web server event handler from handling other events (like open connections or received data). Definitely do not busy loop waiting for time to pass in it. If you need to do any substantial amount of work to handle a web request you're best off setting a shared variable that `loop()` inspects, and then doing the work in `loop()`.